# UIImageView startAnimating blocking main thread even in NSOperation

Tags: animation, uiimageview, png

I am animating a series of PNG sequences of about 250 frames. I am doing this instead of running it as a H264 because I need background transparency.

For some reason even though I load my NSArray and load the startAnimating call inside of an NSInvocationOperation, the UI appears to freeze after startAnimating is called. I can see that while the  images are being loaded into the array the app is still responsive. I am not sure how to stop startAnimating from blocking the main thread.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm that startAnimating is getting called from the main thread?  It must be called from the main thread.

Comment: Its not I have it being called inside the NSInvocationOperation and this does start the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up switching to CoreMedia

Answer (score 0):

It is important that your call to startAnimating be done on the main thread - all UIKit activity must occur on the main threat.  You can do that by changing your method call to something like this:

```
[imageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: The Delay still happens whether its in the main thread or not. I moved it out of the main thread in hopes to stop it from blocking the main thread which didnt work.

Comment: Can you modify your question to clarify the sequence of steps you are doing, when you are seeing the main thread blocked, and for how long it is blocked?